# Remark: unrecognized token warning for the macro concatenation

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings

```
#define DATA_VAR_FILENAME(PROJECT_ID)  QUOTES(..\ ## PROJECT_ID ## _data_var.h)
```

or

```
#define DATA_VAR_FILENAME(PROJECT_ID)  QUOTES(..\##PROJECT_ID##_data_var.h)
```

for the above line I got below warning

> remark: unrecognized token

How to eliminate the warning ?

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it, it looks that you are trying to compose a filename in the preprocessor. This is not possible like that, since the strings that form path names are not tokens for the preprocessor.

Usually there is no need for such a manipulation. String literals are simply concatenated too larger string literals in a later compilation phase. Something like

```
"../" "my_file.h"
```

should do the trick.

You also seem to have the difficulty that on your platform `\` is the path separator. So you'd have to be careful to escape it in string literals, something like `"..\\"`

Comment: Yes, Here I am trying to include file name which is always varies. I have derived the inclusion path with file name, Compilation is working fine, But "remark: unrecognized token" warning is the problem